# Mac only approves password on second entry

Tags: macos, password

Every time I try to open my Mac, it doesn't approve my password the first time but approves it the second time. What is the reason?

Comment: I usually blame my poor typing for that...

Comment: When you say "every time" do you mean **every** time?

Comment: This should never happen - are you absolutely certain you're typing identical password both times?

Comment: Are you using FireVault? Which version of macOS are you running?

Answer (score -1):

The reason you're asked to enter password two times may be because FileVault is enabled. When FileVault is enabled, you're first prompted to enter in your login information to unlock the disk at the EFI Login Window, and then you're prompted to enter in your login information again to go into your actual user account.

Recommended workaround is

1. You turn off FileVault (System Preferences → Security & Privacy → FileVault),  or
2. To allow automatic login when FileVault is turned on, enter this on Terminal

   ```
   sudo defaults delete /Library/Preferences/com.apple.loginwindow DisableFDEAutoLogin
   ```

Please refer to this Apple Support Communities thread for more details
https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7690125

Comment: Thanks for the edit. I'm not sure the answer fits the problem though. The support document linked in the Discussions posts refers to Mavericks (not Sierra).